# In Java how many concurrent threads can run?

Tags: java-threads

If I have an application which runs 5 modules parallely and each module has thread pool which runs 50 threads parallely.
So, in this case 250 thread (5 modules x 50 threads) will run parallely?
I read that each thread runs in separate core, so if we have 8 core system then only 8 threads would run parallely.
If this is the case then how and when other non-pool threads will get chance to execute?

Comment: "I read that each thread runs in separate core" - where? that's wrong. more cores are great, but if there are more threads, they'll just be scheduled among the available cores.

Comment: I read it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676163/how-many-threads-can-run-in-parallel

Comment: I still remember my first intel based single-core laptop, that could run winamp, internet explorer, and word, all at the same time. The basic principle and idea has not changed