# Executor Pool Thread size

Tags: multithreading, executorservice

what factors are necessary to decide about the thread size of excutor pool?
Some mention it depends on cpu core + amount of time thread is taking, but number of cores can vary in different environment

Comment: What instruction set architecture is assumed?

Comment: Re, "number of cores can vary in different environment," Usually there is some means for a program to find out how many cores are available. E.g., this answer shows how a Java program can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759606/801894 . Similar means exist in other languages and/or libraries.

Comment: Also note: The answer is going to depend on what kind of tasks your program gives to the pool. It especially depends on whether they will mostly be compute-bound tasks, mostly I/O bound tasks, or a mix of both. Sometimes, the best way to answer is empirically: Do experiments. Measure the performance.