# Can I check programmatically on a system how many threads would be efficient?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a application that I hard coded to use 4 threads/player.

However, (on a dedicated system) more threads would be more efficient depending on how many players are playing at the same time. (I would theoretically could go up to 30/player.)

Is there a way to measure the maximum number of threads I could use at startup of the calculation?

I guess by having a big calculation and add threads until they start interrupting each other, but I wouldn't know how to check this...

Answer (score 1):

there are so many factors which would ultimately factor in to whether or not a given system could support a certain number of threads.  that said, i would try to correlate how your app performs for X number of threads per cpu in the system.  Once you have determined a reasonable value for X, you can get the [system cpu count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--) for the current system and multiply by X to determine the number of threads to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good starting point `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`

See also here for further discussion: [Finding Number of Cores in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759570/finding-number-of-cores-in-java)