# Java Multithreading with parts of a List

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list with say 1000 entries.

```
public static List<Map<String,Object>> stockSymbolsListMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
```

This list contains stockSymbols that I need to use to pull data from an exchange website. Now to iterate over it and do it one by one is a slow process. i want to break this list in say pieces of 100 and spawn a separate thread for each part to fetch the results. 
Also this process will be repeated every second.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try attempting to write a multithread code using java Thread. And post the issues you come across. Please find multi thread tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) or you can browse for good multi thread tutorials

Comment: My main question is how to work out the list part? What would be the better to split the index in equal size and use them. For multithreading I am using Java's executor service with fixed thread pool.

Comment: You may find using a `ForkJoinPool` here a good fit. There's a great article on it [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue201.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution that does not use any external resources aside from java.util

Instead of using

```
public static List<Map<String,Object>> stockSymbolsListMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
```

I used

```
private static ArrayList<bleh> eh = new ArrayList<bleh>();
```

**Step 1.** Create array

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 450; i++){
        eh.add(new bleh());
    }
```

**Step 2.** Partition the list (Did not spend much time on this, so the code is a tad messy)
Let BLOCK_SIZE = the size of each parition

```
    int listAmount;
    if(eh.size()%BLOCK_SIZE != 0)
        listAmount = eh.size()/BLOCK_SIZE + 1;
    else
        listAmount = eh.size()/BLOCK_SIZE;

    List<bleh>[] lists = new List[listAmount];

    for(int i = 1; i <= listAmount; i++){
        if(i * BLOCK_SIZE < eh.size()){
            lists[i - 1] = eh.subList( (i - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE, eh.size());
        }
        else{
            lists[i - 1] = eh.subList( (i - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
    }
```

**Step 3.** Run the lists concurrently

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for(List<bleh> list : lists){
        executor.execute(new MyThread(list));
    }
```

The MyThread class I used is as such

```
private static class MyThread implements Runnable{
    private List<bleh> eh = null;

    public MyThread(List<bleh> list){
        eh = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("SOME THREAD");
        for(bleh meh : eh){
            System.out.print(meh.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

To use Executors you will need to import

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
```

or simply

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

**UPDATE**
You may want to also scale the amount of threads created in accordance to the amount of threads available in which the following link should be of use, [How to Scale Threads According to CPU Cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980832/java-how-to-scale-threads-according-to-cpu-cores).

Answer (score 1):

Could use Guava's [List.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) to split the list into blocks to process in each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use java's completion service with a fixed thread pool and simply submit a callable for every element in the list. You can control the number which happen at once by changing the size of the thread pool.

The completion service acts like a queue/blocking queue, so you can poll the answers as they are ready.