# Java Threads and number of Cores

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, cpu-cores

Is it recommended that the number of threads in a java application should be less than the number of cpu cores?

If so why is this the case and what are the implications of using threads greater than the number of cpu cores ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to scale threads according to cpu cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980832/java-how-to-scale-threads-according-to-cpu-cores)

Answer (score 6):

You will probably not get any definitive answer on the question of knowing, generally speaking, how many threads an app should have, in relation to the number of core(s) the underlying computer has.

One may also argue that, at the time of PaaS software design and/or elastic clusters, the notion of a fixed number of cores for any given process might be overrated.

Still, the first part of your question :

> Is it recommended that the number of threads in a java application should be less than the number of cpu cores?

This has a definitive answer, which is a "no" (once more : as a general rule). And the reason why, shortly, it that all created threads are not typically running (and maybe more importantly run**able**) at once, meaning there is an opportunity to optimize here.

As a support to this discussion, I'll oppose two ways of creating apps, you could call it "classical" versus "reactive", although this is not a generally acceptable division. Yet, let's use this as a support.

### Classical application design

I label as classical applications that rely mostly on "blocking" calls and/or "thread per request" pattern. Consider the traditional way I/Os are done (socket communication like HTTP or Database connection, hard drive based file reading, ...) : your app thread calls some kind of `read` or `write` method, which usually triggers an OS level call, that blocks your app thread, fills some device buffer at the OS level (say, read from a disk). Once the buffer has received enough data, the OS signals your java app and thread to resume activity, and the `read` method returns with the data from the buffer.

The whole time the OS is working (usually just a tiny fraction of a second, but still some large amount of time compared to your typical GHz CPU speed), your Java thread is in state `BLOCKED_WAITING`, waiting for the OS to signal it can resume. This happens all the time. A code profiler tool, like JProfiler, or YourKit, can help you measure this time. If you do so, you'll notice that in many apps doing I/O, this is a significant part of the so-called "wall time" or "clock time" that is spent... waiting.

So we have one thread waiting, meaning it is not using any CPU time. It can be scheduled out, and the OS is free to give CPU time to anybody else.

Suppose this is a one core CPU, then NOW would be a good time to have another thread to feed the CPU. Meaning having two or more threads could be a good design to maximize CPU usage even on a single core CPU, and get the most out of your hardware.

Most "classical" web applications are typically subject to this type of CPU underuse if you follow the rule of "one thread per CPU core", because Socket communications (or more typically : the time spent waiting for a response to your SQL queries) will incur so much blocking.
If you raise the number of threads your app has, then even if one or two long running requests remain waiting, other faster requests will have runnable threads to run them, and you'll get better CPU usage, and better performance (number of concurrent requests). That is... untill something else reaches saturation (too many heavy requests on your DB, too many simultaneous hard drive reads/writes...)

### Reactive app design

Recognizing this typical behavior of apps, and using different sets of OS features, some application frameworks now use non blocking patterns (even for I/O) to mitigate the above issues. Examples in the Java ecosystem are NIO based networking stacks like Netty, or actor pattern implementations like Akka.

In a typical "reactive" app, one usually abandons the "thread per request" pattern that we have in classical apps (meaning one thread is responsible for handling everything from start to finish of a given user request, and waiting when need be for external resources to become available), in favor of a vastly more modular, and *non*-blocking approach.

Threads are given more technical-grained bits of work to do, and each thread will hand-off work to one another and callbacks to hear back when work they depend upon is done. This "handing of" of units of work means each thread can quickly grab new units of work it is able to handle. Meaning one of two things : you achieve higher CPU usage with far fewer threads in your app (because each can grab work more efficiently, instead of just sitting "waiting") ; or you can instantiate many many more threads because they'll mostly be waiting (not saturating the CPUs), and the dynamical hand-off will still allow for good CPU usage.

### Conclusion

Anyway, you don't design the number of threads solely based on the number of available cores. The nature of your implementation and work dictates the number of optimal threads to create.

On a classical app-design philosophy, the two numbers are more closely related than on a reactive one, but still, we have different profiles :

1. a very simple server app can accomodate many more threads than CPU cores, because it will allow for better throughput (the limit being, say, the output network bandwidth).
2. a SQL heavy app, should be scalled to the point where your app server will saturate the SQL backend. As your app server will be mostly waiting for your SQL server, then this is the limit
3. a mixed application consisting of some SQL heavy work, and some lightweight work, will need precision tuning, because you don't want the stuck threads (those blocked waiting for the DB) starving the light requests that would be served more rapidly
4. a compute intensive program (say, a cryptography service) will probably benefit from a number of threads close to the number CPU cores (if your algorithm is implemented in a classical way), because creating more threads than you are able to run is pointless. In an actor based implementation, creating more threads could actually be a win.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation . In my usecase , the I use a thread pool with a certain number of threads . The job done by each thread is CPU intense and does not involve any wait operations. Also the jobs to be done will always be higher than the number of threads in the pool . So in this case , will having more threads than number of cores be useful ? As the job is only CPU calculations intense and does not involve any handoff or any IO operation ? Or will this result in too many threads waiting for the time slot ?

Comment: In the use case you describe, you don't want to create too many threads, because the CPU is the limit. Creating too much thread will only result in 1) more other ressources being consummed, say, the RAM for the extra running computations, and 2) less efficiency in each task, as the OS will move threads around on various cores (context switching can be exepnsive wrt CPU caches and pipelines for example). So you profile a bit and aim to a number of threads close to your number of CPU cores, say `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`