# How determine the max. number of TPS(transactions per second) can run my server

Tags: java, concurrency, transactions, real-time, threadpool

I write a conccurrent process on Java JDK 1.7 and i need know the number of TPS can run my server. My process should configure its number of TPS in the range [1-x].

Comment: If you want to determine that value... you must execute stress tests... Jmeter is a tool that allows you to create and execute stress test...

Comment: Is there any way using correlation with number of cores or some method getMaxThreadsPerCore?

Comment: Nop, sorry. There is no easy magic formula, because there are so many factors as: hardware, data, algorithms logic magnitude (Big-O) ... However, you're asking for a method as getMaxThreadsPerCore for limiting you thread pool program to a max thread value??

Comment: This method: [availableProcessors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29), will tell you how many threads can run in parallel using a given hardware... Another link of interest: [How to scale threads according to cpu cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980832/java-how-to-scale-threads-according-to-cpu-cores)