# Java Executors Service for a fixed pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have an application which might use hundreds or even thousands of threads simultaneously, for a fixed period of time each.

What should be size of thread pool? - Is there a rule of thumb formula for this number. I understood using the number of processors is an advisable number. Is it the maximum number to set?

Comment: It really depends on the task and where the bottleneck is.  If the process is CPU-bound, then the answer is "yes".  If there's IO involved, the answer is "it depends".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980832/java-how-to-scale-threads-according-to-cpu-cores/36723383#36723383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CPU bound tasks it should be number of processors.

```
int N = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

For I/O bound tasks it can be more than number of processors , because some of threads may not be utilized during I/O intensive tasks. You should estimate ratio of wait time for your average I/O request. Once you get this ratio RT, you can use formula N*(1+RT), where N is number of processors.